# How to retrieve a specific row using SQLite and Cursors?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I want to retrieve a specific user from a `SQLite` database on Android with a provided username using a `Cursor`. I've tried this:

```
String[] fields = new String[] { "username", "email", "dateRegister" };
Cursor c = db.query(tableName, fields, "username ='1234'", null);
```

But it isn't working. How can I retrieve a specific row with the information of a unique column?

Comment: is `c.getString(`, and old cursor?

Comment: @Blackbelt Sorry, a mistake from my part. No other cursor involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
db.query(tableName, null, "username = ?", new String[]{"username"}, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

lots of guys asked the same question ,so please search efficient.

```
String query = "select * from " + tableName + " where "+ KEY_USERNAME + " = '" + uname + "'";
SQLiteDatabase sql = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cur = sql.rawQuery(query, null);
return cur;
```